# Implementing a class in Java

Tags: java, interface

I'm trying to write a driving simulation program and I need some help on the design. I have a interface called RoadObjects which for now contains vehicles and mammals. I need to implement different kind of cars such as trucks, sedans, semis. they have some methods in common and some unique. Later on, I will add other kinds of vehicles and mammals. I don't want to use inheritance and I am trying to do this according to design principles and patterns such as open-closed principle and factory. Now my question is, should I design it like this:

```
RoadObject interface

Vehicle extends RoadObject

Mammal extends RoadObject

SedanImpl implements Vehicle

TruckImpl implements Vehicle

People implements Mammal
```

...

...

or should I just not have vehicle and people interface and do this?

```
RoadObject interface

SedanImpl implements RoadObject

TruckImpl implements RoadObject

People implements RoadObject
```

New question:
I want to use a factory pattern, to chose which kind of vehicles for example. So I make a VechicleImpl and VechicleImplFactory so it might look like this:

```
RoadObject interface

Vehicle extends RoadObject

VehicleImpl implements Vehicle

Mammal extends RoadObject

SedanImpl implements Vehicle

TruckImpl implements Vehicle

People implements Mammal
```

Is this kind of bad design? Because VehicleImpl will have a lot of duplicate methods of SedanImpl,TruckImpl etc. Or if I wanted to have an factory that createVehicle, where should this be?

Comment: Modelling extra classes for `Truck` and `Sedan` may not be required at all, so having one `VehicleImpl` may fulfill all your requirements if you can map the information required for `Truck` and `Sedan` to your `VehicleImpl`.

Comment: @home, but theres the issue of methods that are unique to truck and sedan

Comment: @Home `... they have some methods in common and some unique.` Looks like he already did.

Comment: @Dan In your question, you mentioned that you "don't want to use inheritance" and that you want to utilize the open-closed principle ... The open-closed principle depends on inheritance "closed for modification, open for extension". How do you plan to pull that off? Plus, you are already using inheritance it appears.

Comment: @Matthew Cox: OP asked whether duplicate methods in `VehcileImpl` and its corresponding subclasses are bad design, so I wanted to understand how the duplicates look like. In general a specialization on different types of cars does not make sense, there a better ways to design this - like a list of features in `VehicleImpl`. That's what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are valid, whether you need an explicit abstraction for vehicles depends on your requirements. `SedanImpl`, `TruckImpl` etc. may share some features common to vehicles but not to humen/animals:

```
public interface Vehcile extends RoadObject
    getTires()
    getEngine()
```

As you tagged this in Java common `abstract` classes may be useful as well:

```
public abstract class AbstractVehicle implements Vehicle {
    private Integer tires = 4;

    public Integer getTires() { return this.tires; }

    /* ... */
}
```

So that `TruckImpl` can inherit from `AbstractVehicle`:

```
public class TruckImpl extends AbstractVehicle {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something reasonable:

```
- public interface IRoadObject

- public class People implements IRoadObject

- public class Vehicle

- public class Truck extends Vehicle implements IRoadObject

- public class Sedan extends Vehicle implements IRoadObject
```

However, it's still depending on the requirements. W/o clear requirements as yours, I guess this is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think vehicle & people is a good idea. I would use abstract classes for this.

Also think about behaviors. A school bus has some different behaviors than a motorcycle, and you can implement these with interfaces.

Look [around here](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) for some more ideas.